# Huge delay for *ngIf due to http.get

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading === true"
             class="tableLoading"></mat-spinner>
<div *ngIf="loading === false">
...
</div>
```

So, for some reason, the spinner is taking like 5-8x longer to go away as it is compared to having no condition, yet the data read from my file in my .ts takes the same amount of time.

```
tableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<randomInterface> = new MatTableDataSource<randomInterface>();
loading: boolean = true;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get('assets/abc.json').subscribe((res) => {
    this.tableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<randomInterface>(res as randomInterface[]);
    this.loading = false;
  })
}
```

Since the data is a 3MB~ .json file, I can understand why it would take 8sec~ to load, and without the `*ngIf` in the html it finishes normally, however when I return the loader to the `*ngIf`, all of a sudden the spinner stays there for 45sec+? I'm completely confused as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this method, the content will take time to render, instead go for a overlay type of solution, the html for that will be

```
<div>
    <mat-spinner [hidden]="!loading" class="tableLoading"></mat-spinner>
    ...
</div>
```

You need to style to overlay to be displayed over the grid, you can also add `hidden` to the grid with the reverse condition if necessary, if the grid needs to be hidden!

The advantage of this method is there is no re-rendering of any content and you show/hide the spinner whenever needed, also 3MB is huge, try a virtual scrolling/paging solution for fast user experience!

Comment: Yep, ended up trying it out that way and it worked wonders. Just took the long route and went with `[ngStyle]="{'visibility': loading === false ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}`, but I'm really glad to know why it happens. Thanks!

Comment: Now I just gotta figure if `<mat-paginator>` being extremely slow is a matter of the data size being around 50,000 entries or if it's my code

Comment: @Baltr you need to pass two arguments, take and skip, first page will be take 10 and skip 0, second page will be take 10 and skip 10 and so on, the server needs to return less rows based on the inputs take and skip

Comment: My problem is after the data loads, the paginator linked to the dataSource needs another like, 10~ seconds to actually implement the pagination to the mat-table, between the data loading and the paginator finishing I can just scroll down all the rows.

Comment: Well, just by moving `this.loading = false` from the subscription into the `ngAfterViewInit()` after the paginator initialization basically saved 80% of the paginator initialization time for some reason.

Comment: @Baltr ok then pagination is already implemented then, why is the api size so large then, it should be only Kb size!

Comment: @Baltr Not sure, if you provide a stackblitz with the issue I will surely check!

Comment: Ahahaha, it's because it's a random .json file with garbage objects specifically for load testing. It has like 50000 lines of `{ param1: 1, param2: 'Lorem 1', param3: 'Ipsum 1'}`. From what I've seen and heard, loading .json files is a lot slower than fetching the actual data in a proper format from a database, so it's kind of skewed for time, but it's better than nothing for testing asynchronous stuff.

Comment: Well, it seems it's not the loading of the data that's slow. in fact, it's insanely fast. I presume my bottleneck for displaying the data is going to be the actual table rendering.

Comment: It seems like half of the time it currently takes to load the page is to actually setting up all the data, filter subscriptions, etc... and the other half is spent on finishing the paginator.